# How to use forms in zf2 beta4?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Forms had been remade in zf2 beta4. There are many examples of usage forms for zf1, but no example for new forms. Please give a example or link of new forms usage?

Comment: Doesn't this answer all your questions? http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend_Form+2.0

Comment: no, seems that this thread is extremely old.

Comment: Are forms any less horrid in ZF2?

Comment: Hm, on examples on RockyFord's link forms are worse. But might be is a  matter of habit.

Comment: Never used ZF1 but I heard it was hard to use decorators and so. I do find the new form system easy to build, validate and it is flexible on the view side

Comment: Yes, but in zf1 u should just `echo $form` for form rendering and now you need to open tag, render elements and that close tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, ZF2 is now at beta4 :)

You can see examples of form code over here:

- https://github.com/akrabat/zf2-tutorial
- [Phly Contact](http://git.mwop.net/?a=tree&p=PhlyContact&h=18385303734ab68998d155bcd4748e1c4375d940&hb=adb21fc533d973422e8c8cb8c9f7c906235eda68)

And the unease to read manual:

- https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation/blob/master/docs/languages/en/modules/zend.form.intro.rst
- https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation/blob/master/docs/languages/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.rst

Answer (score 2):

DevZone recently has a post about the new forms in ZF2. Here is a link to the E-mail that links to the examples.

[Link To Email form DevZone](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Forms-now-in-master-td4637456.html)

Answer (score 1):

**ZF2 Beta5** new cool features for **Form** http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=190

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.james-carr.org/2012/09/16/using-select-in-zend-framework-2/

This I found while searching the web, I need to ignore some fields in the input filter. I just whant to validate and filter what I set in input filter not the other things.